# When you throw an exception in a coroutine scope, is the coroutine scope reusable?

Tags: kotlin, error-handling, kotlin-coroutines

I've been having problems figuring out error handling with coroutines that I've narrowed down to this unit test with the following steps:

1. I create a coroutine scope, with any dispatcher.
2. I throw an exception anywhere within this scope in an async block (or even in a nested async block).
3. I call await on the returned deferred value and handle the exception.
4. This is all fine. However, when I try to use the same coroutine scope to launch a new coroutine, this always completes exceptionally with the same exception.

   Here is the test:

   ```
   fun `when you throw an exception in a coroutine scope, is the coroutine scope dead?`() {
       val parentJob = Job()
       val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(parentJob + Dispatchers.Default)

       val deferredResult = coroutineScope.async { throw IllegalStateException() }

       runBlocking {
           try {
               deferredResult.await()
           } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
               println("We caught the exception. Good.")
           }

           try {
               coroutineScope.async { println("we can still use the scope") }.await()
           } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
               println("Why is this same exception still being thrown?")
           }

       }

   }
   ```

Here is the output of the test:

```
We caught the exception. Good.
Why is this same exception still being thrown?
```

- **Why is this happening?**

  - My understanding was that you could handle exceptions normally and recover from them with coroutines.
- **How should I deal with exceptions?**

  - Do I need to create a new coroutineScope?
  - Can I never throw exceptions if I want to keep using the same coroutineScope?
  - Should I return `Either<Result, Exception>`?
  - I've tried using CoroutineExceptionHandler but I still get the same results.

Note I'm using Kotlin 1.3

Comment: From looking at the CoroutineScope javadoc: "cancellation or failure or any child coroutine in this scope cancels all the other children".
So maybe i need to create a new scope for each call.

Comment: Use [`SupervisorJob`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-supervisor-job.html) as `parentJob`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you start a coroutine in a scope (using either `async` or `launch`), then a failure of a coroutine by default cancels this scope to promptly cancel all the other children. This design avoid dangling and lost exceptions.

The general advice here is:

- Don't use `async`/`await` unless you really need concurrency. When you design your code with suspending functions there is no much need to use `async` and `await`.
- If you do need concurrent execution, then follow the pattern:

  ```
  coroutineScope { 
      val d1 = async { doOne() }
      val d2 = async { doTwo() }
      ...
      // retrieve and process results
      process(d1.await(), d2.await(), .... )
  }
  ```

If you need to handle a failure of a concurrent operation, then put `try { ... } catch { ... }` around `coroutineScope { ... }` to catch a failure in any of the concurrently executing operations.

- There are additional advanced mechanisms (like `SupervisorJob`) that allow fine-grained exception handling. You can read more in the documentation https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/exception-handling.html

Comment: Just to be completely sure, if I wrap the call to a suspend function with try/catch and therefore catch an exception, will it cancel the scope and other children? In other words, are caught exceptions different from uncaught in terms of parent coroutine cancellation?