# Catch exceptions from different scope possible?

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

Is this setup somehow possible?

```
scopeA.launch {
    try {
        scopeB.launch {
            throw SomeException()
        }
    } catch (e: SomeException) {
        // Want to catch here
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that answer can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53549113/when-you-throw-an-exception-in-a-coroutine-scope-is-the-coroutine-scope-reusabl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to wish for contradictory things: both launch a concurrent coroutine *and* suspend the current work until it completes, catching possible exceptions. You must decide what you actually want:

1. If you want concurrency, then handle the exception within the child coroutine:

   ```
   scopeA.launch {
       launch(dispatcherB) {
           try {
               throw SomeException()
           } catch (e: SomeException) {
               // handle
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. If you don't want it, don't `launch` a coroutine but use `withContext(dispatcherB)` instead:

   ```
   scopeA.launch {
       try {
           withContext(dispatcherB) {
               throw SomeException()
           }
       } catch (e: SomeException) {
           // handle
       }
   }
   ```
3. If you literally want two coroutines with decoupled lifecycles to communicate, you must introduce a decoupled communication mechanism as well. For example, you can set up a `Channel<SomeException>` or a `Flow<SomeException>`.

Comment: Aren't there cases where different scopes make sense? For instance scopeA is active during the lifetime of an Activity and scopeB is active during an established bluetooth connection. scopeB does bluetooth-io stuff until disconnected (scope canceled). Both scopeA and scopeB should use the main dispatcher but have different lifecycles.

Comment: It would have been great if you had included the use case in your question.

Comment: I tried to reduce the problem to the gist in which two scopes are given. Still I am trying to rethink my design based on your answer.

Comment: I have one idea to solve your problem: establish a `Channel<Exception>` so you can signal exceptions to the other side. It can also work with `Flow`.